# Getting depreciation warning while trying to open appium via Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, appium-android, appium-ios

➜   npm audit

npm ERR! code ENOLOCK

npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.

npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only

npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

After entering command "npm i --package-lock-only" found 0 vulnerabilities. But unable to launch Appium

Getting error message as
(node:24903) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/mjpeg-server/package.json' of './lib/mpegserver'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author